# After setting to install the bundle file, it prompted me to accept the agreement

Tags: vmware

After setting to install the bundle file, it prompted me to accept the agreement, but I'm not sure after that step I'm not able to come out of the instruction page, please assist me on this

Example:

```
sudo ./VMware-Horizon-Client-5.3.0-15208949.x64.bundle
[sudo] password for rajkumar: 
Extracting VMware Installer...done.
You must accept the VMware Horizon Client End User License Agreement
to continue.  Press Enter to proceed.
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the response.

But this will help in reading the agreement after there is no option to proceed with the process. so I added the command to this

command:

**sudo ./VMware-Horizon-Client-5.3.0-15208949.x64.bundle --eulas-agreed**

Answer (score 0):

Use the arrow keys (or Enter) to navigate to the bottom and only then are you allowed to accept. This is necessary as the TeamViewer licence wants to make sure all the licence has been read.